# Stat function dnorm failure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working through a class problem to test if the central limit theorem applies to medians as well. I've written the code, and as far as I can tell, it is working just fine. But my dnorm stat to plot the normal distribution is not showing up. It just creates a flat line when it should create a bell curve. Here is the code:

```
set.seed(14)
median_clt <- rnorm(1000, mean = 10, sd = 2)

many_sample_medians <- function(vec, n, reps) {
  rep_vec <- replicate(reps, sample(vec, n), simplify = "vector")
  median_vec <- apply(rep_vec, 2, median)
  return(median_vec)
}

median_clt_test <- many_sample_medians(median_clt, 500, 1000)

median_clt_test_df <- data.frame(median_clt_test)
bw_clt <- 2 * IQR(median_clt_test_df$median_clt_test) / length(median_clt_test_df$median_clt_test)^(1/3)
ggplot(median_clt_test_df, aes(x = median_clt_test)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = bw_clt, aes(y = ..density..), fill = "hotpink1", col = "white") + 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, mean = 10, sd = 2), col = "darkorchid1", lwd = 2) +
  theme_classic()
```

As far as I can tell, the rest of the code is working properly - it just doesn't plot the dnorm stat function correctly. The exact same stat line worked for me before, so I'm not sure what's gone wrong.

Comment: try `stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 10, sd = 2), ...)`. I don't think the purr syntax works for all ggplot2 function arguments.

Comment: @teunbrand that's what I thought, but apparently it does (see below). This is more of a stats problem than a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line isn't quite flat; it's just very stretched out compared to the histogram. We can see this more clearly if we zoom out on the x axis and zoom in on the y axis:

```r
ggplot(median_clt_test_df, aes(x = median_clt_test)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = bw_clt, aes(y = ..density..),
                 fill = "hotpink1", col = "white") + 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, mean = 10, sd = 2),
                col = "darkorchid1", 
                lwd = 2) +
  xlim(c(5, 15)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5, 15), ylim = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

But why is this?

It's because you are using `dnorm` to plot the distribution of the random variable from which the medians were drawn, but your histogram is a sample of the *medians themselves*. So you are plotting the wrong `dnorm` curve. The `sd` should not be the standard deviation of the random variable, but the standard deviation of the sample medians:

```r
ggplot(median_clt_test_df, aes(x = median_clt_test)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = bw_clt, aes(y = ..density..),
                 fill = "hotpink1", col = "white") + 
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, 
                             mean = mean(median_clt_test), 
                             sd = sd(median_clt_test)),
                col = "darkorchid1", 
                lwd = 2)
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you prefer you could use the theoretical standard error of the mean instead of the measured standard deviation of your medians - these will be very similar.

```r
# Theoretical SEM
2/sqrt(500)
#> [1] 0.08944272

# SD of medians
sd(median_clt_test)
#> [1] 0.08850221
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense. Should the mean also be changed to mean(median_clt_test)? 10 is the theoretic mean of the sample, but the mean(median_clt_test) is not perfectly 10.

Comment: @HannahHarder yes, you could do that. I guess it depends on what you're trying to show.

Comment: @HannahHarder I have updated the answer to move the dnorm curve

Comment: Yeah I think that shows the purpose of the curve better. Thank you so much for all your help and your great explanation!